# Replacing words in string, but ignore those in quotes

Tags: c++, string, replace

I am replacing words in string `content` with this loop:

```
std::string content = "This is original. \"This is original\"";

while (content.find("original") != std::string::npos)
    content.replace(content.find("original"), 8, "replacement");
```

Is there an easy way to not replace "original" to "replacement" when its inside quotes?

So eg.

> This is original. "This is original"

Will be replaced to:

> This is replacement. "This is original"

Instead off:

> This is replacement. "This is replacement"

Comment: Of course there's an easy way: simply write the code to do it. Please try to implement the new logic first, and if you run into a roadblock you can always post your new question here and explain the problem you're seeing. You must make a good faith effort yourself, first, before asking for help on stackoverflow. PS. Your current logic is broken anyway. It will replace the word "unoriginal", if it occurs, leaving "unreplacement" in its place. You will need to fix this, too.

Comment: keep track of  (opening and closing) `"` and check than `"original"` is not inside them.

Comment: @Ted Lingmo, thank you for clarifying that, missed the not.

Comment: Thanks for answers. @SamVarshavchik I want it work this way.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, since you deleted the comment, it would be nice if you removed the downvote too.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to search for whatever comes first, the word to replace or the opening quotes.

If it's the opening quotes you search for the closing quotes and continue the replacement after them.

`std::string::find` allows you to specify the starting position of your search.

The result could look somewhat like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string& replace_except_in_quotes(std::string& content, const std::string& original, const std::string& replacement)
{
    for(size_t pos = 0U; pos < content.size(); /*incremented in body*/)
    {
        size_t nextOriginal = content.find(original, pos);
        if(nextOriginal == std::string::npos)
        {
            break;// All occurences replaced
        }
        size_t nextQuote = content.find('\"', pos);
        bool skipQuotes = (nextQuote != std::string::npos) && (nextQuote < nextOriginal);
        if(skipQuotes)
        {
            nextQuote = content.find('\"', nextQuote + 1);
            if(nextQuote == std::string::npos)
            {
                break; // Missing closing quote
            }
            pos = nextQuote+1;
            continue;
        }

        // Actually replace original with replacement
        content.replace(nextOriginal, original.size(), replacement);
        pos += replacement.size() + 1;
    }
    return content;
}



int main() 
{
    using namespace std;

    string content = "this is original.\"this is original\"";
    cout << replace_except_in_quotes(content, "original", "replacement") << "\n\n";

    content += '\n' + content + '\n' + content + '\n' + content;
    cout << replace_except_in_quotes(content, "original", "replacement") << "\n\n";;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
this is replacement."this is original"

this is replacement."this is original"
this is replacement."this is original"
this is replacement."this is original"
this is replacement."this is original"
```

Godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/oYq3sy

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix, but only for the first word inside quotes, if you have the same word ahead it won't replace it.

[Sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c48ABiDAcLzDvnAK)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; //for sample purposes


int main() 
{
    string content = "this is original. \"this is original\"";
    cout << "Original: " << content << endl;
    while (content.find("original") != std::string::npos)
       if(content.find('"'))
           break;
    content.replace(content.find("original"), 8, "replacement");
    cout << "Replaced: " << content;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @TedLyngmo sorry about that, missed the not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you have a running code link right there.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I writed the code which makes what I wanted.

```
std::string content = "This is original. \"This is original\"";

std::string temp, res;
    unsigned long n = content.length();
    bool instring = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        temp = temp + content[i];
        if(content[i] == '\"' || n == i+1)
            {
                if(instring)
                    {
                        res = res + temp;
                        temp = "";
                    } else
                    {
                        while (temp.find("original") != std::string::npos)
    temp.replace(temp.find("original"), 8, "replacement");
                        }
                        res = res + temp;
                        temp = "";
                    }
                instring = !instring;
            }
    }
    content = res;
```

Thanks for your help.